# JQuery mobile needed for jquery on my mobile site?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 jquery functions on my mobile site. One is a jquery placeholder function and the other one is a Jquery UI widget. Do I need to include the JQuery mobile library for the functions to function properly on all javascript enabled mobile devices? Or not necessary?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not necessary.

jQuery Mobile is a framework you use to simplify creating cross-browser/cross-device mobile-first-websites. It mostly gives you some nice UI widgets and compiles a number of plugins to do trick stuff like AJAX navigation (which allows the transitions between pseudo-pages) and url-rewriting.

To run jQuery plugins you just have to include the proper version of jQuery Core, unless you are including a jQuery Mobile plugin.